# How to denote only some of the specific numbers which their Unicode properties are in the Nd (Decimal_Digit_Number) category?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

While \p{Nd} or \p{Decimal_Digit_Number} contains zero through nine in any language,how can I denote exactly the number 0 and 5 to be in **any** language and preferably without having to write all the Unicodes or numbers in any language?

Currently I'm using this pattern `/^[0۰][5۵]/u` which can denote 0 and 5 in only English and Persian languages

Comment: Define your own custom character class for `0` and `5`. `/^[0۰][5۵]/` is fine if you need to support ASCII and Persion 0 and 5 digits

Comment: Do you need to match more than ASCII and Persian 0 and 5 digits?

Comment: Actually yes, please check this link then you can find out what exactly ‍‍`\p{Nd}` do https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm . I only need 0 and 5 from this list which is provided in all languages @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

The `0`, **zero**, pattern is

```js
[0\u0660\u06F0\u07C0\u0966\u09E6\u0A66\u0AE6\u0B66\u0BE6\u0C66\u0CE6\u0D66\u0DE6\u0E50\u0ED0\u0F20\u1040\u1090\u17E0\u1810\u1946\u19D0\u1A80\u1A90\u1B50\u1BB0\u1C40\u1C50\uA620\uA8D0\uA900\uA9D0\uA9F0\uAA50\uABF0\uFF10\u{104A0}\u{10D30}\u{11066}\u{110F0}\u{11136}\u{111D0}\u{112F0}\u{11450}\u{114D0}\u{11650}\u{116C0}\u{11730}\u{118E0}\u{11950}\u{11C50}\u{11D50}\u{11DA0}\u{16A60}\u{16AC0}\u{16B50}\u{1D7CE}\u{1D7D8}\u{1D7E2}\u{1D7EC}\u{1D7F6}\u{1E140}\u{1E2F0}\u{1E950}\u{1FBF0}]
```

The `5`, **five**, pattern is

```js
[5\u0665\u06F5\u07C5\u096B\u09EB\u0A6B\u0AEB\u0B6B\u0BEB\u0C6B\u0CEB\u0D6B\u0DEB\u0E55\u0ED5\u0F25\u1045\u1095\u17E5\u1815\u194B\u19D5\u1A85\u1A95\u1B55\u1BB5\u1C45\u1C55\uA625\uA8D5\uA905\uA9D5\uA9F5\uAA55\uABF5\uFF15\u{104A5}\u{10D35}\u{1106B}\u{110F5}\u{1113B}\u{111D5}\u{112F5}\u{11455}\u{114D5}\u{11655}\u{116C5}\u{11735}\u{118E5}\u{11955}\u{11C55}\u{11D55}\u{11DA5}\u{16A65}\u{16AC5}\u{16B55}\u{1D7D3}\u{1D7DD}\u{1D7E7}\u{1D7F1}\u{1D7FB}\u{1E145}\u{1E2F5}\u{1E955}\u{1FBF5}]
```

In JavaScript, you can use

```js
const five=String.raw`5\u0665\u06F5\u07C5\u096B\u09EB\u0A6B\u0AEB\u0B6B\u0BEB\u0C6B\u0CEB\u0D6B\u0DEB\u0E55\u0ED5\u0F25\u1045\u1095\u17E5\u1815\u194B\u19D5\u1A85\u1A95\u1B55\u1BB5\u1C45\u1C55\uA625\uA8D5\uA905\uA9D5\uA9F5\uAA55\uABF5\uFF15\u{104A5}\u{10D35}\u{1106B}\u{110F5}\u{1113B}\u{111D5}\u{112F5}\u{11455}\u{114D5}\u{11655}\u{116C5}\u{11735}\u{118E5}\u{11955}\u{11C55}\u{11D55}\u{11DA5}\u{16A65}\u{16AC5}\u{16B55}\u{1D7D3}\u{1D7DD}\u{1D7E7}\u{1D7F1}\u{1D7FB}\u{1E145}\u{1E2F5}\u{1E955}\u{1FBF5}`;
const zero=String.raw`0\u0660\u06F0\u07C0\u0966\u09E6\u0A66\u0AE6\u0B66\u0BE6\u0C66\u0CE6\u0D66\u0DE6\u0E50\u0ED0\u0F20\u1040\u1090\u17E0\u1810\u1946\u19D0\u1A80\u1A90\u1B50\u1BB0\u1C40\u1C50\uA620\uA8D0\uA900\uA9D0\uA9F0\uAA50\uABF0\uFF10\u{104A0}\u{10D30}\u{11066}\u{110F0}\u{11136}\u{111D0}\u{112F0}\u{11450}\u{114D0}\u{11650}\u{116C0}\u{11730}\u{118E0}\u{11950}\u{11C50}\u{11D50}\u{11DA0}\u{16A60}\u{16AC0}\u{16B50}\u{1D7CE}\u{1D7D8}\u{1D7E2}\u{1D7EC}\u{1D7F6}\u{1E140}\u{1E2F0}\u{1E950}\u{1FBF0}`;
const regex = new RegExp(`[${zero}${five}]`, 'gu');
console.log('0٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦೦൦෦๐໐༠၀႐០᠐᥆᧐᪀᪐᭐᮰᱀᱐꘠꣐꤀꧐꧰꩐꯰０5٥۵߅५৫੫૫୫௫౫೫൫෫๕໕༥၅႕៥᠕᥋᧕᪅᪕᭕᮵᱅᱕꘥꣕꤅꧕꧵꩕꯵５'.match(regex))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDg5HR/1).

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to use `\p{Nd}` itself to not write all the Unicodes

Comment: @ghazaleheslamifard There is no way to use it, and more, if you decide to use it, your regex will be even longer because you will need to add all unwanted chars as exceptions to this negated character class - `[^\P{Nd}]`. What I posted is **the only viable and possible approach: *create custom class***. I did not check if the chars are consecutive in the Unicode table (that would let shorten the pattern), you can go ahead and check that.